# How can I simulate a SQL insert statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm working on a web application that uses NHibernate. Sometimes when there is a bug in the SQL generated by NHibernate, the error I get is extremely unhelpful:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The code that threw the error generated dozens and dozens of SQL statements, which are stored in a log, such as:

```
INSERT 
INTO
    ShipOrder (ShipContactName, ShipAddress1, ShipAddress2, ShipAddress3, ShipCity, ShipStateCode, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountryCode, ShipProvider) 
VALUES
    ('Tobias Funke', '12345 Anywhere Pl', NULL, NULL, 'Anytown', 'AA', '12345', 'US', 'UPS GROUND')
```

I want to try running this query to see if it is the cause of the error. Is there a way I can simulate the insert in SQL Server Management Studio so I don't create dummy data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in a [transaction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx), and [rollback](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) instead of [commit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT 
INTO
    ShipOrder (ShipContactName, ShipAddress1, ShipAddress2, ShipAddress3, ShipCity, ShipStateCode, ShipPostalCode, ShipCountryCode, ShipProvider) 
VALUES
    ('Tobias Funke', '12345 Anywhere Pl', NULL, NULL, 'Anytown', 'AA', '12345', 'US', 'UPS GROUND')
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```